# What if typing judgements were propositions?

Tags: type-theory

Suppose we created a modified type theory in which typing judgments like $x : X$ are not judgments at all; rather, they're propositions.

Would this be a bad idea? If so, why?

A good answer should offer (reasonably) explicit examples about the problems or limitations of such an approach. I want to understand this well enough that I can explain it to a friend, say.

Comment: Well, type theory was invented to avoid Russel's paradox...

Comment: @Berci, you're saying we can construct a liar sentence?